# Don't know how to obtain the elements of a netCDF file

Tags: import

Running Mathematica on my home computer, I can list the contents of a netCDF file but can't read them, as shown in the image of my session [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWTae.jpg)]. On my work computer I can both list contents and read them, as shown in the image of my session [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCLOH.jpg)]. These two computers are very similar--both MacBook Pro's with Intel Core processors and 16GB memory--and they are executing the same Mathematica commands.

I find the error message that I get on my home computer particularly mysterious. It says that the import element "is not present when importing as HDF5." Where did I ask Mathematica to import netCDF data as HDF?

Comment: How'd you build NetCDF? Per its docs you can build it with or without HDF5 support. Maybe Mathematica can tell whether you did. In any case what happens if you stick a `"Datasets"` before `"time"`? I'm just looking at ``System`ConvertersDump`FileFormatData["NetCDF", "ImportElements"]`` and that is there for both it and HDF5.

Comment: just to eliminate the obvious - have you checked the file hashes on both computers to be the same?

Comment: oh, and are you using exactly the same Mathematica versions on both computers? OS versions?

Comment: Thank you b3m2a1, adding "Datasets" before "time" fixes the problem!